# How can I use two monitors with my radeon 6450 graphics card?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have a computer with an integrated gpu on the motherboard. Because I wanted to use two monitors and my motherboard only has one VGA port, I bought an ATI radeon HD 6450. Both my monitors have a VGA connector, so I also bought an adapter (VGA to DVI). The VGA port on the card works fine, but I can't get the DVI port to work. Does anybody know how I can get this to work?

Comment: Which OS? Did you install the ATI drivers?  Do the graphic properties report both monitors are attached? Have you tried both monitors on that port?  Exactly which Radeon card is it, and which DVI->VGA adapter did you use?

Comment: I use win 7, installed the latest drivers from the ATI website, windows doesn't detect the monitor that is connected to the DVI port. The card is the ATI Radion HD 6450.

Comment: Typically when you have a discreet graphics card, the on-board video will be disabled. Many times there are options in the BIOS that *may* let you use both. Look around your BIOS to see if there are any settings regarding your on-board video.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try that, but is there any way to connect both monitors to the videocard?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Move-windows-between-multiple-monitors

Comment: @Ewout Not if the video card only has one VGA/DVI port.

Comment: It has a VGI port, a DVI port and a HDMI port.

Comment: @Ewout Oh, I misunderstood. I was under the impression that your video card only had one port and you were trying to use the on-board VGA port and the one on the video card. My mistake.

Have you extended the display to the other card, such as in the link that Mr. Fooz added? Does the PC detect that there are two display devices?

Comment: No, that's exactly the problem. When I connect my second screen to the DVI port (with an adaptor), windows doesn't detect the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. From my understanding, you are attempting to connect two monitors to your new discrete card and then use that to manage displays.

If your BIOS outputs to both monitors (which it should, since that seems to be the default with more modern boards), then that confirms that everything is working. In that case, I cannot offer much advice beyond cleaning out the connectors between the monitor, adapter, and video card itself. As well, ensure that Windows is recognizing the monitors in the first place. Either check the AMD Catalyst Control Centre, Windows Screen Resolution configuration, or even check Device Manager to see if they show up. I'm not sure if they show up in device manager, but I do know that Piriform's [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy) *does* show connected monitors, so I imagine Windows device manager does as well.

However, if your second monitor is completely dead, I would look into checking for hardware failure on the monitor, the video card's DVI port, the adapter, and any cables in between. I personally would replace the adapter, since they seem to have the highest failure rate in my set-ups. As mentioned above, I would still definitely try to clean out the connectors to make sure there isn't a piece of dust in between. But first, you should try replacing the first monitor with the second ("dead") one to see if it even works at all.

While I hold a little doubt the hardware is at fault here, it is entirely possible.. unless you mentioned that "the monitor outputs" somewhere and I missed it.

tl;dr

- Check AMD/Windows configuration
- Clean out the connectors
- Swap out the monitors if the second one doesn't output **at all**
- (No system POST on the monitor at all) Replace the adapter, cables, etc. to see if they're the fault of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to obtain latest Catalyst drivers and try to detect second monitor(enable) in Display options (AMD/ATI) Display Manager, and also you need check is there any conflicts in BIOS with integrated graphics like Josh already proposed. Also in every manual that comes with Graphic cards is explained a way to connect cabling to multiple displays. Maybe Yours problem is in DVI/VGA adaptor and/or cabling.